# Convert matrix elements from str to int in Python

Tags: python, scripting

I need to convert the elements of a matrix from str to int (after I read them from a file).
I don't want to use any external library.

This is what I produced so far and it's working, but I'm not happy with it (not very pythonic):

```
def str2int(matrix):
    n = 1 
    m = 1 
    if type(matrix) is ListType:
        n = len(matrix)
        if type(matrix[0]) is ListType:
            m = len(matrix[0])
    new_matrix = []
    i = 0 
    while i < n:
        new_matrix.append([])
        j = 0 
        while j < m:
            new_matrix[i].append(int(matrix[i][j]))
            j += 1
        i += 1
    return new_matrix
```

Any better ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Type checking is a bad ways to do things in Python, and if you are going to type check, at least use `isinstance()` over `type(x) is SomeType`. Likewise, iteration by index is a really bad idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [list comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw):

```
return [[int(i) for i in row] for row in matrix]
```

Comment: Could also use `map` for the inner comprehension: `return [map (int, row) for row in matrix]`

Comment: This is what I wanted. Thanks a lot (also for the tutorial).

Comment: @lxop: I used a list comp there too because Python 3's `map()` returns an generator, not a list; the list comp works across versions.

Comment: I see.  I haven't moved into Python 3 yet, so that's good to know